# ORA-00904 error when using define

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple select statement using two variables in define:

```
DEFINE MEMBER_NR = 1503530453; 
DEFINE CARD_TYPE = AA;
SELECT * FROM CARDS y JOIN PEOPLE p
ON p.INDIVIDUAL_ID = y.INDIVIDUAL_ID
WHERE p.NR = &MEMBER_NR
AND y.TYPE = &CARD_TYPE
ORDER BY y.FROMDATE DESC;
```

Unfortunately when running this query, ORA-00904 error occurs on line

```
AND y.TYPE = &CARD_TYPE
```

Error details:

```
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 23 Column: 25
```

What could be the reason? I suspect bad type of CARD_TYPE variable, but I'm not enough versed in SQL to solve this.

Comment: Can you please provide the table structure.

Comment: Does SQL Developer really support `DEFINE` like that? It's not a SQL command, and to my knowledge only supported by SQL\*Plus

Comment: I've made a small mistake in bug description. Actually MEMBER_NR line works and gives proper results.Only after reaching CARD_TYPE error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

My example is based on Scott's schema as I don't have your tables.

This is what you have (an error):

```
SQL> define e_ename = 'KING'
SQL>
SQL> select empno, ename, sal
  2  from emp
  3  where ename = &e_ename;
where ename = KING
              *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: "KING": invalid identifier


SQL>
```

As ENAME column is VARCHAR2, you should enclose the variable into single quotes:

```
SQL> select empno, ename, sal
  2  from emp
  3  where ename = '&e_ename';

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7839 KING             5000

SQL>
```

Got it?